# How can I do a for loop in shell

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, awk, scripting

I have the following in a file:

```
[Class:ABCD_EFGH_IJK]
list.0=VALUE001*
list.1=VALUE002*
list.2=VALUE003*
list.3=VALUE004*
[Class:ABCD_EFGH_IJK:app:ABCD_EFGH_IJK]
condition=true

[Class:LMNO_PQRS_TUV]
list.0=VALUE004*
list.1=VALUE005*
list.2=VALUE006*
list.3=VALUE007*
[Class:LMNO_PQRS_TUV:app:LMNO_PQRS_TUV]
condition=true
```

I have another script that runs using the class name and list value as its arguments. For example:

```
./myscript VALUE001* ABCD_EFGH_IJK
```

I need use a for loop to iterate over each class and grab each value to run my script. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Doing this is in Python is very straight-forward. But you want the solution in shell only right?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I think I want a solution using shell.

Comment: wrt `I need use a for loop` - no, you definitely do not. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/133219). [edit] your question to include the expected output plus what you've tried so far.= so we can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you asked for:

```
$ awk -F'[]:=[]' '/Class:/{class=$3} /^list/{print $2, class}' file |
    xargs -n2 echo ./myscript
./myscript VALUE001* ABCD_EFGH_IJK
./myscript VALUE002* ABCD_EFGH_IJK
./myscript VALUE003* ABCD_EFGH_IJK
./myscript VALUE004* ABCD_EFGH_IJK
./myscript VALUE004* LMNO_PQRS_TUV
./myscript VALUE005* LMNO_PQRS_TUV
./myscript VALUE006* LMNO_PQRS_TUV
./myscript VALUE007* LMNO_PQRS_TUV
```

Remove the `echo` when you're ready to actually have `./myscript` called.

Answer (score 0):

A terrible example (too complex) using the Hold space in `sed` is

```
sed -nr '/\[Class:/ {s/\[Class:(.*)\]/\1/;h};/list/{G;s#.*=(.*)\n#./myscript \1 #p}' file
```

In words:
When you see a line with `Class:`, copy the classname into the Hold space.
When you see a line with `list`, append the Hold space (the classname) to the current line,
and use the inserted newline character for modifying the first part.
Print the line.

The `#` is used when the replacement string has a `\`.
Remembered matched strings in `()` are recalled with `\1`.